# How to fill the options inside a select2 dropdown based on the value selected from the previous[above] dropdown?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I want to bring a dropdown with user search using select2 js, where the values inside the dropdown must be filled based on the company selected , which is a dropdown above this dropdown.

I am using XAMPP version 5 with MYSQLI.

```
<?php 

include 'db.php';

?> 
<html>
<head>
 <link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 <script src="../assets/js/core/jquery.3.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <link href="../assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <script src="../assets/js/core/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js'></script>

</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off">


<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-2">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-10">

<div class="form-group row">
<label for="sel1" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Company  :</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<select onChange="company_info();"   id="company_list"  required class="form-control select2" name="company_id"  >
<option value="">Select Company</option>
<?php 
$companyDetails=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM company  order by id desc  ");

while($company = mysqli_fetch_assoc($companyDetails))
{

echo "<option value='".$company['id']."'";

echo " >".$company['compName']."</option>";
}
?> 
</select>
</div>
</div>

<div id="companyDesc"></div>

<div class="form-group row">
<label for="pthings" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">To dos :
</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<select id="selUser" style="width: 200px;">
<option value="0">- Search -</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>


<div class="form-group">

<button type="submit" name="add" class="btn btn-default greenbtn btnrightalign">Submit</button>
</div>
</div>

</form>
</body>
</html>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#selUser").select2({
ajax: { 
url: "getData.php",
type: "post",
dataType: 'json',
delay: 250,
data: function (params) {
return {
searchTerm: params.term // search term
};
},
processResults: function (response) {
return {
results: response
};
},
cache: true
}
});
} );


function company_info()
{
var compId = $("#company_list").val(); 
if (compId="")
{ 
$.ajax({url:"getCompDetails.php",
data:{'CompId':compId},
type:'POST',
success: function(result)
{     

$("#companyDesc").html(result); 

}});
}
else
{
$("#companyDesc").html('');
}

}

</script>
```

## getCompDetails.php:

```
if(isset($_POST['CompId']))
{ 

  $sql=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT  comp_desc from company where id=".$_POST['CompId']); 
  while($run_sql  =mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
  {

    $compDesc=$run_sql ['comp_desc'];
  }




  $str='<div class="form-group row  ">
  <label for="sel1" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Company Details  :</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
  <textarea class="form-control" name="copm_details" rows="10" cols="20">'.$compDesc.'</textarea>
  </div> </div> 
    ';

  echo $str;
}
```

## getData.php

```
<?php
include("db.php");

if(!isset($_POST['searchTerm'])){ 
  $fetchData = mysqli_query($con,"select * from order order by id");
}else{ 
  $search = $_POST['searchTerm'];   
  $fetchData = mysqli_query($con,"select * from order where order_no like '%".$search." %'");
} 

$data = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($fetchData)) {    
  $data[] = array("id"=>$row['id'], "text"=>$row['order_no'].'-'.$row['sales_order_no']);
}
echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

Expected output:

I want the options in select2 dropdown based on the value selected from company.

For ex:
On selecting company "ABC Pvt Ltd" , the  To dos dropdown(select2) values are "Header,Footer,Sidebar,Navigation,Registration,Login".

On selecting company "RAM Pvt Ltd" , the  To dos dropdown(select2) values are "Registration,Login,Search,Payment,Logout".

And the user search functionality should be working fine.

Actual output:

From my code , I am able to get a select2 dropdown , where the values inside the option is not based on the option selected from the company dropdown.

And the user search functionality is not working fine.

Answer (score 0):

you need add your select2 post data with company id:

```
$("#selUser").select2({
    ajax: { 
        url: "getData.php",
        type: "post",
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        data: function (params) {
            return {
                searchTerm: params.term,
                compId: $("#company_list").val() //here your company data
            };
        },
        processResults: function (response) {
            return {
                results: response
            };
        },
        cache: true
    }
});
```

and then you can get company id with `$_POST["compId"]` and add to your query on get data.php

Comment: Hi , now I am able to get the option inside the select2 dropdown based on the company selected .But on typing some search text in select2 dropdown , it shows no results found.

Comment: @GayathriA can you update your question please, so i know what progress you've been made

Answer (score -1):

From a quick glance at your code, I'm guessing you're probably getting a MySQL error. On getData.php, it looks like you're querying a table called **order**. Since order is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html#keywords-5-7-detailed-O) in MySQL, those queries will almost certainly throw an error unless the table name is enclosed in backticks. For example:

```
$fetchData = mysqli_query($con,"select * from `order` order by id");
```

Comment: I have changed the 'order' table name to 'data_order'.And I have passed the compId in post , so that I can able to get options in select 2 dropdown based on company selected.But on typing some serch text in select2 dropdown , it shows no results found.

Comment: You may have another error in your SQL syntax. In the line `$fetchData = mysqli_query($con,"select * from data_order where order_no like '%".$search." %'");`, I'm seeing a space before the second '%'. That could be causing your query to return zero results. Try deleting that space and see if it helps.

Comment: Yes , you are right . The issue is with the space . Now its working fine.Thanks for identifying my error.